# button alignment issue on html,css

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want something like this https://www.producthunt.com/e/best-of-february-2017 
[image]

On hover external link and save must appear on the same line, but for me the alignment is not coming.
Thanks in advance!

snippet is below and this is the image result of my code[image]

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.sec-b', function() {
      $(this).find("#external").show();
    }).on('mouseleave', '.sec-b', function() {
      $(this).find("#external").hide();
    });
  }); <
/script>

<
script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.sec-b', function() {
      $(this).find("#down").show();
    }).on('mouseleave', '.sec-b', function() {
      $(this).find("#down").hide();
    });
  }); <
/script>
```

```css
.sec-b {}

#gb {
  margin-top: 2%;
}

#gb1 {
  margin-top: -13%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#gb2 {
  margin-top: -1%;
  margin-left: 15%;
}

.but {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
}

.but span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #9E9E9E;
  border-left: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
  width: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.but:hover {
  padding-right: 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.but:hover span {
  width: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

#up {
  margin-left: 53%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

#down {
  margin-left: 45%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

#external {
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

#comment {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.fa-caret-up {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.fa-comment {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.fa-download {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.fa-external-link {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="sec-b">

  <img src="img/gboard.jpg" height="100" width="100" id="gb">
  <p id="gb1">Gboard by Google</p>
  <p id="gb2">Google search,emoji</p>
  <span class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm but">
       TECH
         <span>+</span>
  </span>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="external"><span class="fa fa-external-link"></span> 
          </a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="down"><span class="fa fa-download">&ensp;SAVE</span> 
          </a>

  <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="up"><span class="fa fa-caret-up">&ensp;2662</span> 
          </a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="comment"><span class="fa fa-comment">&ensp;42</span> </a>
  <hr>


</div>
```

Comment: When the code snippet is run, an error is reported: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" on line 136

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved your issue by make some changes in CSS and HTML. Here is its fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kirtan3d/Ldecbmnv/1/)
I've tried to achieve same result as producthunt.com example. So, I've almost rewrite your code. Please take a look mainly on HTML and CSS:

#### HTML:

```
<div class="sec-b">
  <img src="https://ph-files.imgix.net/1c1c487a-379f-4f0c-99cd-cb6048a85606?
 auto=format&auto=compress&codec=mozjpeg&cs=strip&w=80&h=80&fit=crop" 
height="80" width="80" align="left">
  <p>Gboard by Google<br>
  <small>Google search, emoji</small></p>
  <div class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm but">TECH<span>+</span></div>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-right" id="comment"><span class="fa fa-comment">&ensp;42</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-right" id="up"><span 
class="fa fa-caret-up">&ensp;2662</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-right" id="down"><span 
class="fa fa-download">&ensp;SAVE</span></a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-right" id="external"><span class="fa fa-external-link"></span></a>
  <hr>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.sec-b {
  display: block;
  padding:0.5rem;
}
.sec-b p, .sec-b small {
  margin-bottom:0;
}
.sec-b > img {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}
.sec-b .btn {
  margin: 0.25rem 0.25rem;
}
.sec-b:first-child .btn {
  margin: 0.25rem 0.25rem 0.25rem 0;
}
.but {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.but span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #9E9E9E;
  border-left: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
  width: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.but:hover {
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.but:hover span {
  width: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.fa-caret-up {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
.fa-comment {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
.fa-download {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
.fa-external-link {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
```

#### JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).find("#external").hide();
  $(document).find("#down").hide();
  $(document).on('mouseenter', '.sec-b', function() {
    $(this).find("#external").show();
  }).on('mouseleave', '.sec-b', function() {
    $(this).find("#external").hide();
  });
});
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.sec-b', function() {
  $(this).find("#down").show();
}).on('mouseleave', '.sec-b', function() {
  $(this).find("#down").hide();
});
```

Still it is very messy, you have to cleanup your code. You can merge "external" & "down" IDs and can write single JS for hide/show it on mouse over.

Comment: This is so perfect ! Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. It's using nested flexboxes and all id's are replaced with classes. Javascript is not required.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
  border: thin solid lightgray;
}

.rightColumn {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin-left: 1em;
  max-height: 100px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.rightColumn>p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.icons {
  display: flex;
}

.btn.down,
.btn.external {
  display: none;
}

.but {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
}

.but span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #9E9E9E;
  border-left: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
  width: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.but:hover {
  padding-right: 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.but:hover span {
  width: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.container:hover .btn.external {
  display: inline-block;
}

.container:hover .btn.down {
  display: inline-block;
}

.fa-caret-up {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.fa-comment {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.fa-download {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.fa-external-link {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100/00ff00" width="auto" height="100px">
  <div class="rightColumn">
    <p>Gboard by Google</p>
    <p>Google search,emoji</p>
    <div class="icons">
      <span class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm but">TECH<span>+</span></span>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm external">
        <span class="fa fa-external-link"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm down">
        <span class="fa fa-download">&ensp;SAVE</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm up">
        <span class="fa fa-caret-up">&ensp;2662</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm comment">
        <span class="fa fa-comment">&ensp;42</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its perfect , but wherever i hover i want external link and save button appear @Gerard

Comment: I updated the code. Now you can hover anywhere on the container

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sec-b {}

#gb {
  margin-top: 2%;
}

#gb1 {
  margin-top: -13%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#gb2 {
  margin-top: -1%;
  margin-left: 15%;
}

.but {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
}

.but span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #9E9E9E;
  border-left: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
  width: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.but:hover {
  padding-right: 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.but:hover span {
  width: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

#up {
  margin-left: 53%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

#down {
  margin-left: 45%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

#external {
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

#comment {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.fa-caret-up {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.fa-comment {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.fa-download {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.fa-external-link {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="sec-b">
  
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/X64En0aW6jkvDnd5kr16u-YuUsoJ1W2cBzJab3CQ5lObLeQ3T61DpB7AwIoZ7uqgCn4=w300" height="100" width="100" id="gb">
  
  <p id="gb1">Gboard by Google</p>
  <p id="gb2">Google search,emoji</p>
 
 
 <span class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm but" style="margin-top: -5px;">TECH<span>+</span></span>

<div class="pull-right" style="margin-right:5px">

<a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm external">
        <span class="fa fa-external-link"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm down">
        <span class="fa fa-download">&ensp;SAVE</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm up">
        <span class="fa fa-caret-up">&ensp;2662</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm comment">
        <span class="fa fa-comment">&ensp;42</span>
      </a>
</div>

<hr>
</div>
```